# Using Excel Office Scripts for Engineering Application

Tags: office-scripts

When I first looked at Office Scripts I was thinking it is good for simple formatting. I have an Excel VBA addin (.xlam) engineering app that does estimation and optimization for a product. I'm wondering how extensive an app you can create in Office Scripts. It has interesting opportunities for collaboration. Questions:

Is there a runtime limit for a script? I envision some optimizations taking 20-30 minutes.

Is there a size limit on scripts? My VBA addin is 2500 lines.

Is there a good way to manage large Typescript files?

Is there a runtime memory limit?

Is there a limit on JSON fetch data size/number limits? My addin uses a local Access database to hold engineering data. I envision creating a lot of JSON files from the database.

Is there any way to use GIT or Devops for backing up scripts.

Is there a way to use Visual Studio or VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a good idea to look into Office.Js add-ins. Office Scripts is built on top of Office.js. You can see the differences [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/add-ins-differences).

Office.js was designed with developers in mind. And it will give you many of the options that you're seeking (git support, use of VSCode, the ability to manage several typescript files, etc.) You can read more about using the Excel JavaScript API within Office.js [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview).

Answer (score 0):

For your application I would recommend looking at [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab). Script Lab will let you prototype and save your prototype to GitHub as a gist.

- Is there a runtime limit for a script? I envision some optimizations taking 20-30 minutes.

  - There is no runtime limit on your local machine.
- Is there a size limit on scripts? My VBA addin is 2500 lines.

  - There is no size limit on scripts. note: scripts are currently limited to a single file.
- Is there a good way to manage large Typescript files?

  - Scripts are currently limited to a single file.
- Is there a runtime memory limit?

  - How much memory are you anticipating your program needing?
- Is there a limit on JSON fetch data size/number limits? My addin uses a local Access database to hold engineering data. I envision creating a lot of JSON files from the database.

  - See the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- Is there any way to use GIT or Devops for backing up scripts.

  - Not easily.
- Is there a way to use Visual Studio or VSCode?

  - Yes. You can use vscode.dev (The Web version of Visual Studio Code).